# Sublime Text 3 Regex, find multiple - replace with one

Tags: regex

Using Sublime Text 3. Im lokking for a `([b0-9-])` strings in my text docs. Having trouble to replace it with single character or a few. e.g:  `b110-1.jpg` & `b110-2.jpg` should be replaced with `pic` so after all this will look like `1.jpg` or `pic.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the character class to repeat one or more times. This should be achieved by adding `+` quantifier next to that character class.

```
[b0-9-]+
```

replace with `pic` or `1`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5bG5/7)

Comment: Thank you! And if its something like ps-c410-1.jpg or ps-c410-2.jpg, how can I find these particular strings only, without selecting anything else.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z\d]+-\d\b`

Comment: Works great, last question. If I have html structure like: img src="ps-c410-13.jpg" alt="ps-c410-13.jpg" and I need to replace only everything in alt=" " withouth touching anything in src=" ", is it possible to do and could you make an example please?

Comment: `alt="[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z\d]+-\d+\.jpg"` replacewith `alt=""`